# Why does tempdir() adds extra slash at end of directory tree on osx?

Tags: macos, r, file, path

Somewhere along the way `tempdir()` prepends an extra forward slash before the directory at the end of the tree. Is there any reason for this and are there any cases in which it matters? According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11965) from another site, double slashes in a directory tree don't matter (but they do at the start of a path), so why does `R` on osx add an extra one?

Could this be considered a bug or is there a situation where it's necessary? In the example both paths resolve correctly:

```
tempdir()
  [1] "/var/folders/ck/1x5j5jvx5mq17clf5r32gg540000gn/T//Rtmpp6VKKK"
normalizePath( tempdir() )
  [1] "/private/var/folders/ck/1x5j5jvx5mq17clf5r32gg540000gn/T/Rtmpp6VKKK"

setwd( tempdir() )
write.table("" , file="This is a test.txt")

system( paste0( "cd " , tempdir() , "; ls -a" ) )
  .
  ..
  This is a test.txt

system( paste0( "cd " , normalizePath( tempdir() ) , "; ls -a" ) )
  .
  ..
  This is a test.txt
```

As an aside, I realise that it's not very relevant for this site, but perhaps someone with more `osx` experience could shed light on why `normalizePath()` changes `/var` to `/private/var`? Is this to do with aliases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in the implementation of `tempdir`. Per the function documentation<sup>[1]</sup>:

> The environment variables `TMPDIR`, `TMP` and `TEMP` are checked in turn and the first found which points to a writable directory is used: if none succeeds `‘/tmp’` is used.

`TMPDIR`, by default, contains a trailing slash which `tempdir()` seems to not notice when composing its result. A better implementation would remove the trailing slash first, if it exists.

And yes, on Mac OS X, `/tmp` is a symbolic link to `/private/tmp`.

[1] https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tempfile.html

Comment: +1 Thanks. That was so fast I can't accept the answer for another 8 minutes.